# How Creation and Annihilation operator transform under an unitary transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, second-quantization, unitarity

\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal H}= \sum_{i,j} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}_i H_{i,j}\hat{\psi}_j
\end{align}
The $\mathcal H$ is the full second quantized Hamiltonian for a system and $H$ is the single particle Hamiltonian in basis $\left|i\right>= \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}_i \left|0\right> $, where ${i}={1,2,\ldots, N}$.
And $H$ commutes with $U$
$$
U H U^{\dagger}= H
$$
Under a unitary transformation an annihilation and a creation operator transform as
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal U} \hat{\psi}_i \hat{\mathcal U}^{-1} &= \sum_{j} U_{i,j}^{\dagger} \hat{\psi_j} \\
\hat{\mathcal U} \hat{\psi}_i^{\dagger} \hat{\mathcal U}^{-1} &= \sum_{j}\hat{\psi_j}^{\dagger} U_{j,i} 
\end{align}
Here $\hat{\mathcal U}$ is the unitary operator acting on Fermion Fock space. and $U$ is the unitary operator acting on single particle Hilbert space.

I want to proof the last two equations. I have no idea where to start form. Any help is highly appreciated.
**Source of doubt**: [Topological phases: Classification of topological insulators and superconductors of non-interacting fermions, and beyond](http://stacks.iop.org/1402-4896/2016/i=T168/a=014001?key=crossref.861694c20b0f47efa9e2b7f7c29e6033) (section 3.1.1)

Comment: The equations could be considered a definition of $U$. Do you have another definition and want to show equivalence?

Comment: can you provide any source in this regard? @fqq

Comment: You don't need a source to read about it.  It's just plug and chug from the definition, Every book I have ever read  says neither more nor less that what you have here,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that your two equations are the *definition* of how a  unitary transformation $U$ acting on the single-particle Hilbert space induces a unitary transformation  $\mathcal U$ on the  many-particle Fock space. They need to be suplimented with the additional  equation 
$$
{\mathcal U}|0\rangle = |0\rangle
$$
where $|0\rangle$ is the no-particle Fock-space state. Once this is done the action of ${\mathcal U}$ on any Fock-space state is determined.

As a definition, no "proof'' is to be expected or desired.

It is important that $U$ be unitary, so that the (anti)-commutation relations
$$
[\hat \psi_i,\hat \psi^\dagger_j]_\pm = \delta_{ij}
$$
be preserved.

Comment: In this perspective (with which I agree) one could want to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is a linear operator, and that it is unitary.

Comment: $\mathcal U$ is *defined* to be linear, but one does need to prove unitarity, but this is easy ---  at least at the formal level. Of course  Fock spaces are tricky analytically.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the creation and annihilation operators transform just like any other operator (keeping in mind that here the operators and transformations are in the Fock space), i.e.,
$$
a,a^\dagger\rightarrow UaU^\dagger, Ua^\dagger U^\dagger.
$$
On the other hand, a result of action of a creation/annihilation operator is a wave function (in the Fock space) that belongs to the same Hilbert space. Since wave function transforms as
$$
|\phi\rangle \rightarrow U|\phi\rangle,
$$
we should also have
$$
a|\phi\rangle, a^\dagger|\phi\rangle \rightarrow Ua|\phi\rangle,
 Ua^\dagger|\phi\rangle.
$$